# Insert multiple values in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a MySql database and need some of the tables to have pre-created values. Its like a user needs to select a species of the pet he owns and I give him values from table "pet_species", like ["Fish","Dog","Cat",...,"Lizard"].
Also I have a table like "pet_breed" with pet_species_id, pet_breed_id, pet_breed_name. So is it possible to add the values in MySql Workbench or somewhere else, so it will look for all constraints while I add values, and then generate a right sql script to create or update this tables.
Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: can't use an script to insert all default values?

Comment: To me it's not really clear what you mean, but it sounds a bit like foreign keys: you would add the allowed values into a table, and a foreign key (that basically links a column(s) of a table to that column(s), it "refers" to it) will enforce the constraint (that the value has to exist in the reference table) when the user inserts a row or updates the value. But it will not be automatically displayed, your client app has to read and display the values. Maybe that is what you are looking for.